# Eclipse php debugger terminates

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I have an eclipse environment set up using xdebug as the debugger.  This configuration has been working fine for months.  I have not changed anything.  In the middle of a coding session, the debugger started terminating unexpectedly at the beginning of my app.  Thought it was a coding error, but eventually I simplified the code to the point where it terminates on even the most simple line of code:

```
$test = 1+1;
```

The behavior is that the debugger runs as expected until it reaches a breakpoint.  Usually the next step results in termination.  "Usually", because I have found that it will work for an include statement, in which case the first line of code in the included file causes a termination.

Eclipse Helios Release 2, 20110301-1815.  OSX 10.7.4.  Tried it with both the internal browser and Firefox.  Using MAMP as the development stack.  Tried restarting Eclipse. Tried restarting Apache & MySQL.  Tried restarting the Mac.

Out of ideas.  Suggestions?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll remove the comment then and I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues with Netbeans. The problem turned out to be XDebug, because it becomes pretty unstable when there are watched expressions. Try removing everything from watches. Also try disabling variable watching completely or tweek with the depth of watched variables.